# DbUpdateException when updating data through a view

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, view

I have a database which consists of two tables `FirstTable` and `SecondTable`". And there is a View `CustomView`. `CustomView` gets values from both tables `FirstTable` and `SecondTable`.

In my edmx, I mapped view into my model. I am getting data from the database which works fine. But if I try to update any data I am getting `DbUpdateException`.

Here is my code,

```
public UpdateData(string something)
{
    using (var database = new MyDatabase())
    {
        var records = database.Context.CustomView.ToList();
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
           database.Context.CustonView.Attach(record);
           record.Something = something;
        }
        database.Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception,

```
{System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException: Syntax error near 'set' on line 16
   at iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SACommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

If I map table `FirstTable` and update its values, it is working fine, but for view it fails.

Comment: Can you execute the update in sql directly? What is the view definition and the update sql statement? (and the dbms for that matter)

Comment: I don't know the exact query but it gets updated (some other c++ applications update database through the view). I am connecting to a Sybase SQL anywhere database. I think problem is in Entity Framework, I have missed something, don't know,

Comment: Can I get query from entity framework?,

Comment: Yes you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework

Comment: I am not using linq query. Examples show sql of selecting information.

Comment: var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)database.Context.CustomView).ToTraceString();